# SQL Server 2000 : Upgrade from Personal Edition to Enterprise Edition

Tags: upgrade, sql-server-2000

I've never tried this before but this is what I'm attempting to do :

- Backup all the databases
- Copy current `master.mdf` and `master.ldf` to another location (for later purpose)
- Uninstall SQL Server 2000 Personal Edition
- Install SQL Server 2000 Enterprise Edition (SP4)
- Stop the newly installed server, and replace the `master.mdf` and `master.ldf` with those old two files above
- Restart server

I've done this before, but only with Enterprise Edition, after reinstalling SQL Server I'll just have to replace the master file and everything is fine.

Will it work in this case ?

Answer (score 2):

I would like to post this as answer what is point in upgrading to SQL server 2000 which is outdated completely without any support. Even it is not good for testing purpose. Its like using typewriter in era or super computers.

Dont uninstall personal edition first. Install enterprise move databses by backup restore method. If you restore master msdb databases you would not need to move logins and jobs.

Please refer to below link

https://www.barracudaware.com/files/docs/9.00/help/restoring_microsoft_sql_server_2000_master_database.html

Comment: To add to your post, there is no longer upgrade paths for SQL 2000 beyond SQL 2008. You must buy 2005/2008 version before going up to 2012/2014.

Comment: Sometimes you are bound by third parties, or corporate decision makers. We have some critical systems still running on DOS, why I hear you ask... well because they work. Sometimes you don't have a choice.

Comment: Ya I am aware about it thank you, but you should actively inform user about its downside which was my motto in the post. I know I cannot cajole him to switch to SS2012/14 decision lies upto him/management

Comment: @Shanky : thanks, but this still does not answer my question. I was asking if my normal steps is good for this upgrade. By the way, i can't upgrade to 2005, 2008 because the software we're using does not support higher level of SQL Server. And this Personal Edition was installed mistakenly instead of Enterprise Edition and now i have to fix it.

Comment: As I already said you need to go using backup restore method for user as well as system databases. Please check link posted about feasibility on restoring system databases in 2000. If you restore all users and system databases from personal to enterprise you would get all data, logins, users and jobs.